# Angular page with Factory, Service and Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory

I am  fairly new to angular and am trying to run an angular page however no matter what I try, I continuously run into an error that says that I didnt create an angular module.

Failed to instantiate module HotelApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/nomod?p0=Hote... blah blah blah

my code looks like this

```
(function () {
            "use strict";
            angular.module(APPNAME)
                .factory('$hotelService', hotelServiceFactory);

            hotelServiceFactory.$inject = ['$methodRepository', $methodRepository];

            function hotelServiceFactory($methodRepository) {
                var hotelServiceObject = AjaxScripts;
                console.log("Hotel Service", hotelServiceObject);
            }
        })();

        (function () {
            "use strict";

            angular.module(APPNAME)
                .controller("HotelController", hotelController);

            hotelController.$inject = ['$scope', '$hotelService'];

            function TracksController($scope, $hotelService) {
```

I'm mostly puzzled about why it says that my module is not instantiated while I specifically declared the APPNAME variable in both the script and in the ng-app

edit 
I currently have

```
 (function () {
                "use strict";
                angular.module("HotelApp", [])
                    .factory('$hotelService', hotelServiceFactory);

                hotelServiceFactory.$inject = ['$methodRepository', $methodRepository];

                function hotelServiceFactory($methodRepository) {
                    var hotelServiceObject = AjaxScripts;
                    console.log("Hotel Service", hotelServiceObject);
                }
            })();
```

yet it is still not working..

Comment: The title could get the question closed. Update it.

Comment: you can click on (or copy paste) that errors.angularjs.org link and actually have an explanation on why you get that error. the other people have already pointed out the problem correctly anyhow..

Comment: remove immediate invocation function your code will work.

Answer (score 2):

Where are you creating the module. The module must be created in this way. 
`angular.module('APPNAME',[]);`
Then you can use `angular.module('APPNAME')` to create controller,factory or ...
But only while creating module [](for dependency injection) inside module should be there.

Comment: I understand what your saying. APPNAME isnt the actual name its a variable that has a value of the app actual name 'HotelApp'

Comment: Then show the full code where you're initializing the module with dependency. And where that variable is.

Comment: This should work ....                                                                              (function () {
                "use strict";
                angular.module("HotelApp", [])
                    .factory('$hotelService', hotelServiceFactory);

                hotelServiceFactory.$inject = ['$methodRepository'];

                function hotelServiceFactory($methodRepository) {
                    var hotelServiceObject = AjaxScripts;
                    console.log("Hotel Service", hotelServiceObject);
                }
            })();

Answer (score 1):

The `hotelServiceFactory.$inject` property is defined wrong.

```
//DO this
hotelServiceFactory.$inject = ['$methodRepository'];
//NOT this
//hotelServiceFactory.$inject = ['$methodRepository', $methodRepository];

function hotelServiceFactory($methodRepository) {
    var hotelServiceObject = AjaxScripts;
    console.log("Hotel Service", hotelServiceObject);
}
```

That is causing a compile error.

---

Also controller declaration doesn't match controller function name.

```
angular.module(APPNAME)
    .controller("HotelController", hotelController);

hotelController.$inject = ['$scope', '$hotelService'];

//DO this
function hotelController($scope, $hotelService) {
//NOT this
//function TracksController($scope, $hotelService) {
```

Answer (score 0):

you left the `2nd` parameter which is `[]` i.e. `DI` (Dependency Injection) in `module`

```
angular.module('APPNAME', [])
```

Answer (score 0):

> change this

```
angular.module(APPNAME)
```

> With this

```
  angular.module('HotelApp',[])
```

Answer (score 0):

First Step in angular is module a starting point for your app where you write like this

```
angular.module('APPNAME',[]);
```

first Parameter refers to your application name and second is dependency Injection means that your app further requirement like any plugins,services,directives...etc

Comment: I tried this but it does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: have you include `ng-app = "APPNAME"` in your main index.html